# Android emulator can't install apps

Tags: android

I'm trying to install and run the default 'hello world' app on the emulator, but whenever I try to run it I get this error on install:

```
[2014-07-07 16:07:07 - Test] Android Launch!
[2014-07-07 16:07:07 - Test] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-07 16:07:07 - Test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-07 16:07:18 - Test] Uploading Test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-07 16:07:27 - Test] Installing Test.apk...
[2014-07-07 16:08:22 - Test] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-07-07 16:08:22 - Test] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-07 16:08:24 - Test] Launch canceled!
```

This is the logcat output when that happens:

```
?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of main
07-07 19:36:52.410: E/logwrapper(40): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:36:52.540: E/logwrapper(43): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:36:54.420: I/lowmemorykiller(45): Using in-kernel low memory killer interface
07-07 19:36:55.370: I/qemu-props(48): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
07-07 19:36:55.410: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:55.410: I/qemu-props(48): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=48m
07-07 19:36:55.710: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:55.710: I/qemu-props(48): received: ro.config.low_ram=true
07-07 19:36:56.070: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:56.070: I/qemu-props(48): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=160
07-07 19:36:56.320: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:56.370: I/qemu-props(48): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=0
07-07 19:36:56.620: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:56.620: I/qemu-props(48): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=none
07-07 19:36:56.770: I/qemu-props(48): receiving..
07-07 19:36:56.770: I/qemu-props(48): exiting (5 properties set).
07-07 19:36:56.940: I/installd(54): installd firing up
07-07 19:36:57.260: I/DEBUG(50): debuggerd: Jun 23 2014 23:40:35
07-07 19:36:57.260: I/DEBUG(50): --------- beginning of system
07-07 19:36:58.370: I/Vold(47): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
07-07 19:36:58.530: D/Vold(47): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
07-07 19:36:59.600: I/Netd(49): Netd 1.0 starting
07-07 19:36:59.800: W/InterfaceController(49): Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
07-07 19:37:04.160: D/Vold(47): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
07-07 19:37:07.800: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): SurfaceFlinger is starting
07-07 19:37:07.800: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
07-07 19:37:07.820: D/libEGL(51): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
07-07 19:37:08.700: D/libEGL(51): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-07 19:37:09.900: D/gralloc_goldfish(51): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): using (fd=14)
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): id           = 
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): xres         = 320 px
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): yres         = 480 px
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): xres_virtual = 320 px
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): yres_virtual = 960 px
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): bpp          = 16
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): r            = 11:5
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): g            =  5:6
07-07 19:37:09.990: I/gralloc(51): b            =  0:5
07-07 19:37:10.030: I/gralloc(51): width        = 49 mm (165.877548 dpi)
07-07 19:37:10.030: I/gralloc(51): height       = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
07-07 19:37:10.030: I/gralloc(51): refresh rate = 651.04 Hz
07-07 19:37:10.110: E/SurfaceFlinger(51): hwcomposer module not found
07-07 19:37:10.110: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 1536001
07-07 19:37:10.190: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
07-07 19:37:10.190: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL_SLOW_CONFIG selected!
07-07 19:37:10.190: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL information:
07-07 19:37:10.190: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): vendor    : Android
07-07 19:37:10.190: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
07-07 19:37:10.190: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
07-07 19:37:10.230: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): Client API: OpenGL_ES
07-07 19:37:10.230: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
07-07 19:37:10.270: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
07-07 19:37:10.270: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL_SLOW_CONFIG selected!
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL information:
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): vendor    : Android
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): Client API: OpenGL_ES
07-07 19:37:10.270: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
07-07 19:37:10.400: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): OpenGL ES informations:
07-07 19:37:10.400: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): vendor    : Android
07-07 19:37:10.400: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4
07-07 19:37:10.400: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
07-07 19:37:10.400: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
07-07 19:37:10.450: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
07-07 19:37:10.450: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096
07-07 19:37:10.590: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
07-07 19:37:10.590: W/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL_SLOW_CONFIG selected!
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGL information:
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): vendor    : Android
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): Client API: OpenGL_ES
07-07 19:37:10.590: I/SurfaceFlinger(51): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
07-07 19:37:11.200: D/SurfaceFlinger(51): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0xb835f448
07-07 19:37:18.810: E/SurfaceFlinger(51): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
07-07 19:37:19.660: D/libEGL(92): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
07-07 19:37:19.870: D/libEGL(92): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-07 19:37:21.180: D/gralloc_goldfish(92): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-07 19:37:29.930: I/ARMAssembler(92): generated scanline__00000077:03010102_00000A01_00000000 [  9 ipp] (30 ins) at [0xb60191f0:0xb6019268] in 20000000 ns
07-07 19:37:30.000: I/ARMAssembler(92): generated scanline__00000077:03545402_00000A01_00000000 [ 31 ipp] (52 ins) at [0xb6019270:0xb6019340] in 10000000 ns
07-07 19:37:34.070: D/AndroidRuntime(52): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
07-07 19:37:35.580: D/AndroidRuntime(52): CheckJNI is ON
07-07 19:37:37.770: I/mediaserver(53): ServiceManager: 0xb722a460
07-07 19:37:37.830: I/AudioFlinger(53): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
07-07 19:37:38.700: I/CameraService(53): CameraService started (pid=53)
07-07 19:37:40.190: D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(53): Emulated camera list: 
07-07 19:37:40.300: I/CameraService(53): Loaded "Emulated Camera Module" camera module
07-07 19:37:41.260: I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(53): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
07-07 19:37:41.470: I/AudioFlinger(53): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Default audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
07-07 19:37:41.560: I/AudioFlinger(53): HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
07-07 19:37:42.610: I/AudioMixer(53): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
07-07 19:37:42.620: I/AudioFlinger(53): Using module 1 has the primary audio interface
07-07 19:37:42.630: I/AudioFlinger(53): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb5f93008 ready to run
07-07 19:37:42.870: W/AudioFlinger(53): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
07-07 19:37:43.020: W/AudioFlinger(53): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
07-07 19:37:43.070: W/AudioFlinger(53): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
07-07 19:37:43.100: E/AudioFlinger(53): no wake lock to update!
07-07 19:37:43.150: E/AudioFlinger(53): int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
07-07 19:37:43.170: I/AudioFlinger(53): loadHwModule() error -2 loading module r_submix 
07-07 19:37:43.170: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(53): could not open HW module r_submix
07-07 19:37:43.170: I/AudioPolicyService(53): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
07-07 19:37:47.380: D/dalvikvm(52): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-07 19:37:47.680: D/dalvikvm(52): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-07 19:37:48.600: D/dalvikvm(52): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-07 19:37:48.620: D/dalvikvm(52): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-07 19:37:48.620: D/dalvikvm(52): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
07-07 19:38:00.920: D/dalvikvm(52): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
07-07 19:38:21.340: E/memtrack(52): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-07 19:38:21.350: E/android.os.Debug(52): failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-07 19:38:28.650: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(52): Profiling disabled.
07-07 19:38:29.360: I/Zygote(52): Preloading classes...
07-07 19:38:29.420: D/dalvikvm(52): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
07-07 19:38:29.550: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 8% free 527K/568K, paused 34ms+18ms, total 121ms
07-07 19:38:30.810: D/dalvikvm(52): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
07-07 19:38:30.910: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 4% free 601K/620K, paused 6ms+6ms, total 90ms
07-07 19:38:37.190: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 3% free 645K/664K, paused 26ms+3ms, total 145ms
07-07 19:38:39.870: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 3% free 702K/720K, paused 24ms+23ms, total 120ms
07-07 19:38:43.280: D/dalvikvm(52): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
07-07 19:38:43.460: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 5% free 726K/760K, paused 6ms+24ms, total 172ms
07-07 19:38:52.880: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 2% free 777K/788K, paused 25ms+4ms, total 149ms
07-07 19:39:04.060: E/logwrapper(278): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.220: E/logwrapper(279): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.300: E/logwrapper(280): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.390: E/logwrapper(281): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.460: E/logwrapper(282): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.560: E/logwrapper(283): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.780: E/logwrapper(284): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
07-07 19:39:04.830: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 29K, 4% free 803K/836K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 294ms
07-07 19:39:11.210: D/TextLayoutCache(52): Using debug level = 0 - Debug Enabled = 0
07-07 19:39:14.760: I/dalvikvm(52): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-07 19:39:14.850: D/MtpDeviceJNI(52): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
07-07 19:39:14.950: I/dalvikvm(52): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-07 19:39:15.020: I/dalvikvm(52): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-07 19:39:15.290: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 2% free 851K/864K, paused 26ms+26ms, total 166ms
07-07 19:39:17.940: D/dalvikvm(52): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
07-07 19:39:18.140: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 4% free 875K/908K, paused 8ms+53ms, total 196ms
07-07 19:39:19.070: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 2% free 935K/952K, paused 26ms+5ms, total 210ms
07-07 19:39:21.160: E/EmojiFactory_jni(52): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
07-07 19:39:22.980: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 29K, 4% free 961K/992K, paused 28ms+5ms, total 194ms
07-07 19:39:28.740: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 30K, 4% free 984K/1020K, paused 26ms+27ms, total 212ms
07-07 19:39:36.370: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 3% free 1011K/1040K, paused 26ms+28ms, total 245ms
07-07 19:39:38.520: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 3% free 1046K/1072K, paused 17ms+5ms, total 219ms
07-07 19:39:39.320: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 2% free 1091K/1112K, paused 27ms+29ms, total 233ms
07-07 19:39:40.280: D/MDnsDS(49): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
07-07 19:39:40.300: D/MDnsDS(49): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
07-07 19:39:40.300: D/MDnsDS(49): Going to poll with pollCount 1
07-07 19:39:40.940: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 79K, 7% free 1123K/1208K, paused 17ms+17ms, total 161ms
07-07 19:39:42.170: D/dalvikvm(52): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
07-07 19:39:42.370: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 4% free 1169K/1208K, paused 19ms+37ms, total 183ms
07-07 19:39:43.240: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 44K, 4% free 1184K/1232K, paused 33ms+16ms, total 175ms
07-07 19:39:44.110: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 53K, 6% free 1196K/1264K, paused 19ms+20ms, total 163ms
07-07 19:39:53.340: I/System(52): Loaded time zone names for "" in 8193ms (7622ms in ICU)
07-07 19:39:57.610: I/System(52): Loaded time zone names for "en_US" in 4247ms (3773ms in ICU)
07-07 19:39:57.850: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 253K, 17% free 1357K/1616K, paused 26ms+19ms, total 235ms
07-07 19:40:00.590: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 238K, 13% free 1631K/1872K, paused 212ms, total 216ms
07-07 19:40:03.490: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 232K, 12% free 1781K/2020K, paused 21ms+18ms, total 254ms
07-07 19:40:05.910: I/Zygote(52): ...preloaded 1481 classes in 96543ms.
07-07 19:40:17.670: D/dalvikvm(52): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 11% free 1800K/2020K, paused 20ms+20ms, total 246ms
07-07 19:40:17.710: I/Zygote(52): Preloading resources...
```

I've tried making new AVDs and cleaning my project, but it doesn't seem to help.  Does anyone know what causes this/how to fix it?

edit: When I try making an AVD with the GPU box checked I get an infinite loop of this:

```
07-07 22:26:45.960: E/EGL_emulation(90): Failed to establish connection with the host
07-07 22:26:45.960: E/(90): Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new virtual device and set the GPU emulation mark to true in Hardware properties.

Comment: I tried that too, it spammed errors, I'll add to body

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit the AVD skin to use “skin with dynamic hardware controls”